# How to reshape using two variables

Tags: stata, reshape

Suppose I have this data:

```
group    obs    data    data_A    data_B
1        1      7_a     7_a       
1        2      4_b               4_b  
1        3      1_a     1_a     
2        1      5_b               5_b
3        1                  
4        1      3_b               3_b
4        2      4_b               4_b
4        3      9_a     9_a     
4        4      8_b               8_b
```

`data_A` and `data_B` are constructed based on `data`. They follow the rule that they take on the value of `data` if `data` ends in `a` for `data_A` and `b` for `data_B`; if data is blank, `data_A` and `data_B` both stay blank.

I would like to reshape the data to be as follows:

```
group    data_A1    data_A2    data_B1    data_B2    data_B3
1        7_a        1_a        4_b                     
2                              5_b              
3                                            
4        9_a                   3_b        4_b         8_b
```

where the number of columns is automatically determined by the number of values.

`7_a` and `9_a` are in `data_A1` because they are the first instance of an `a` variable in their respective groups. `1_a` is in `data_A2` because it is the second instance of an `a` variable in its group, and so on.

How can this be done?

(I know about `reshape` and that this can be used in similar situations.)

Comment: I took the liberty to rephrase the question based on a comment you made to an initial answer I provided, and that I'll delete. I provide a new answer that better suits your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with loops. Not very elegant, but it works.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
group    obs    str3(data    data_A    data_B)
1        1      7_a     7_a           ""
1        2      4_b       ""        4_b  
1        3      1_a     1_a          ""
2        1      5_b      ""         5_b
3        1       ""        ""       ""
4        1      3_b       ""        3_b
4        2      4_b       ""        4_b
4        3      9_a     9_a          ""
4        4      8_b       ""        8_b   
end

drop data
list, sepby(group)

*----- what you want -----

quietly foreach i in A B {

    bysort group (obs) : gen count_`i' = sum(!missing(data_`i'))
    summarize count_`i', meanonly

    forvalues j = 1/`r(max)' {
        gen data_`i'`j' = ""
        replace data_`i'`j' = data_`i' if count_`i' == `j'
    }

    drop count_`i'
}

drop data_?

collapse (firstnm) data_*, by(group)

list
```

Another way uses `reshape`s and `fillin`:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
group    obs    str3(data    data_A    data_B)
1        1      7_a     7_a           ""
1        2      4_b       ""        4_b  
1        3      1_a     1_a          ""
2        1      5_b      ""         5_b
3        1       ""        ""       ""
4        1      3_b       ""        3_b
4        2      4_b       ""        4_b
4        3      9_a     9_a          ""
4        4      8_b       ""        8_b   
end

drop data

list, sepby(group)

*----- what you want -----

// first reshape
reshape long data_ , i(group obs) j(j) string

// counts per group j
bysort group j (obs) : gen count = sum(!missing(data_))

// concatenate and rectangularize
gen j2 = j + string(count)
fillin group j2

// drop some observations
bysort group j2 (data_) : drop if _n < _N | inlist(j2, "A0", "B0")

// keep necessary variables
keep group j2 data_

// second reshape
reshape wide data_, i(group) j(j2) string

list
```

I find the solution with loops more intuitive.

The data structure you're aiming for is rather odd. It's always a good idea to insert some context along with your ultimate goal.

Comment: I ended up using the loop code. I added:
`foreach i of varlist data_A1- data_B3 {`
     `bys group obs: replace `i' = `i'[_n-1] if !missing(`i'[_n-1])`
`}`        and then only keep the last observation by group.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Roberto that this is kind of an odd thing to do. Here's another interesting way to get there:

```
clear
input float(group obs) str3(data data_A data_B)
1 1 "7_a" "7_a" "" 
1 2 "4_b" "" "4_b" 
1 3 "1_a" "1_a" "" 
2 1 "5_b" "" "5_b" 
3 1 "" "" "" 
4 1 "3_b" "" "3_b" 
4 2 "4_b" "" "4_b" 
4 3 "9_a" "9_a" "" 
4 4 "8_b" "" "8_b" 
end

* verify assumptions about the data
isid group obs, sort

* concatenate values across obs
by group (obs): replace data_A = data_A[_n-1] + " " + data_A
by group (obs): replace data_B = data_B[_n-1] + " " + data_B

* the last obs of the group contains all values
by group: keep if _n == _N

* split each concatenated string
split data_A
split data_B

drop obs data data_A data_B
list
```